# Como puedo guardar los datos de un array JSON a una lista JAVA

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, jsonobject, jsonarray

estoy intentando guardar los datos de un array JSON a una lista en java, pero no se como
Este es mi codigo:

```
 JSONArray jarray = peticionHttpGet("payment_methods", "GET");
            
        String bankpag = "";
        
        ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            bankpag = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            while (bankpag.equals("PSE")) {
                listdata = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("financial_institutions"); 
               //en la linea de arriba bota error; jsonarray cannot be convert to arraylist java.
            }
            
            listdata.add(jarray.toString());
        }

        return listdata;
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Es demasiado importante agregues que jarray es el que obtienes al realizar la petición, para dar una respuesta concreta, saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como el error dice no puede convertir de tipo de dato a otro, al menos no usando la "igualdad" -> `cosaTipoB = otraCosaTipoA`.  Visita la [info oficial de JSONArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html).

Otra cosa, no estoy seguro, talves podrías clarificar, que no quieres convertir nada, sino *extraer* un dato, y este dato (un string) guardarlo en el arraylist.

Si es así entonces tu lógica está en la dirección correcta, solo te haz confundido un poco. También parece que intentas comparar otros valores. Pero mantiendo las cosas simples, Intenta entonces lo siguiente:

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    String bankpag = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"); // aqui recibes un string
    if (bankpag.equals("PSE")) { // aqui comparas el string
        listdata.add(bankpag); //agrega el string si el valor es correcto
        // o si es otro valor el que necesitas...
        String elValorQueQuiero = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("financial_institutions").toString();
        listdata.add(elValorQueQuiero);
    }
}
return listdata;
```

Personalmente, no guardaría Strings de jsons en variables, prefiero mantenerlo como Json hasta el último momento antes de ser "impreso" o "guardado" a un archivo. En todas otras situaciones tendrías que reconvertir a json de cualquier manera. En otras palabras usar:

`ArrayList<JSONArray> listdata = new ArrayList<>();`

De esta manera podrías simplemente:

```
ArrayList<JSONArray> listdata = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
    if (jarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name").equals("PSE")) { 
        JSONArray miFinancialInstitutionsArray = jarray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("financial_institutions");
        listdata.add(miFinancialInstitutionsArray);
    }
}
return listdata;
```

Y ya cuando sea que necesites el string aplicas el `JsonObject.toString()` pero antes creo que obtienes más beneficions mantiendolo como JSON.

OJO: es tu responsabilidad validar la existencia o contenido de ese `financial_institutions`.

Extras generales, cómo mejorar tu pregunta:

- Danos un ejemplo de como se ve ese json input (jarray).
- Danos un ejemplo de como quieres que se vea al final listdata.
  Eso nos ayudaría más rápido a darte soluciones más precisas y más limpias :)

Mucha suerte!